# php get name of array

Tags: php, arrays

```
$shortcodes['video_section'] = array(
    'no_preview' => true,
    'params' => 'xxx',
    'shortcode' => '[sc1][/sc1]',
    'popup_title' => __('Video Section', THEME_NAME),
    'shortcode_icon' => __('li_video')
);

$shortcodes['image_section'] = array(
    'no_preview' => true,
    'params' => 'yyy',
    'shortcode' => '[sc2][/sc2]',
    'popup_title' => __('Image Section', THEME_NAME),
    'shortcode_icon' => __('li_image')
);

$shortcodes[] = $th_shortcodes;
```

How can I retrieve the name of each array and then access to the key and value:

for example I need to loop throught $shortcode and get the array main name: `'image_section' 'video_section'`

Then to retrieve the value of some key. I know how to retrieve key and value but really don't understand how to get the name of the declared array. If i do: `var_dump($value);` I saw the name of the array but how to access to it?

Comment: `foreach($shortcodes as $key => $value){ echo $key; }`? `$key` = "video_section" / "image_section".

Comment: @putvande; you have forgotten something perhaps.

Comment: I only get with this the $key and value but not the name of the array...

Comment: it's not "name", it's called "key".

Comment: the hell do you mean as `name`, is this the variable name?

Comment: Yes the keys here: `$shortcodes['video_section'] ` this key `'video_section'` not the child keys and values...

Comment: @freaky: you seem to not understand that `'video_section'` is a key of the `$shortcodes` array.

Comment: `video_section` is a key  of the array named `shortcodes`. And most answers below will get you that key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

```
foreach($shortcodes as $key => $value) {
  echo $key // echoes "vide_section" and "image_section" 

  foreach($value as $innerKey => $innerValue) {
    echo $innerKey // echoes 'no_preview', 'params', 'shortcode', 'popup_title', 'shortcode_icon' twice
  }
}
```

Note that `$value` in this case refers to arrays, you can foreach again to access the inner values.

Comment: Thank you but it don't work... I get all the array keys and values, not the name of each array

Comment: What do you mean by "name"? Arrays don't have names, they have keys (like 'vide_section' and 'image_section'). If you want to get the key names inside the inner arrays you have to `foreach` again.

Comment: It works but it's the $innerKey that output the key of each array... So I need 3 loop to reach child keys of each array.... strange

Comment: If you know the outer key names you can do `foreach(shortcodes['video_section'] as $innerKey => $innerValue)` and `foreach(shortcodes['image_section'] as $innerKey => $innerValue)`, but in this case if you add a third array you will have to write that too as `foreach`.

Comment: In fact I don't now the key name. I find why I need 2 loops before to get my key name. It was because of this : `$shortcodes[] = $th_shortcodes;` . Only need this `$shortcodes = $th_shortcodes;`

Answer (score 0):

Use the array_flip function on the array

```
$array = array_flip($shortcodes);
```

Comment: To use `array_flip` you need to ensure that all the values are unique strings or numbers. Note that this is not the case here, since all the values are arrays.

Answer (score 0):

There's [`array_keys()`](https://www.php.net/array_keys):

```
$keynames = array_keys($shortcodes);
```

You could foreach throught it:

```
foreach($shortcodes as $key=>values){ echo $key; }
```

or flip the values with the case (though this last one I don't recommend), and than foreach through those. But array flip is best to be left alone in this case (though I nice function to keep in the back of your head).

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php), where it goes through each item on array, based on creation order.

```
foreach($shortcodes as $key => $value) {

   // $key represents video_section for 1st iteration and image_section for 2nd.
   //Here each are array, so you can again iterate over $value and get each item .

   foreach($value as $key2 => $value2) {
      //here keys are no_preview, params and so on on subsequent iterations.
   }
}
```